# Split, insert and join

Tags: perl

Here's I want to archive. I want to split a one-liner comma-separated and insert @domain.com then join it back as comma-separated.

The one-liner contains something like:

> username1,username2,username3

and I want to be something like:

> username1@domain.com,username2@domain.com,username3@domain.com

So my Perl script that I tried which doesn't not work properly:

```
my $var ='username1,username2,username3';
my @tkens = split /,/, $var;
my @user;
       foreach my $tken (@tkens) {
           push (@user, "$tken\@domain.com");
       }
my $to = join(',',@user);
```

Is there any shortcut on this in Perl and please post sample please. Thanks

Comment: What is your current error output, if any?

Comment: There's no error but trying to print what is inside the $to shows a next line on @domain.com for username3. I am not sure what's causing it.

Comment: I found out what is causing this. I have to trim trailing white spaces both left and right to make it properly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split, transform, stitch:

```
my $var ='username1,username2,username3';
print join ",", map { "$_\@domain.com" } split(",", $var);
# ==> username1@domain.com,username2@domain.com,username3@domain.com
```

Comment: One thing I have learned is that I need to add this to trim trailing white spaces both left and right  $var =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

Comment: if you are finding whitespace, then you have not been posting your actual script.  Perhaps you are accepting from input or line-by-line from a file or STDIN?  In that case, use chomp() on your input string.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a regular expression substitution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var = "username1,username2,username3";
# Replace every comma (and the end of the string) with a comma and @domain.com
$var =~ s/$|,/\@domain.com,/g;
# Remove extra comma after last item
chop $var;
print "$var\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have good answers. Here I am just telling why your script is not working. I didn't see any `print` or `say` line in your code, so not sure how you are trying to print something. No need of last line in your program. You can simply suffix `@domain.com` with each value, push to an array and print it with `join`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var = 'username1,username2,username3';
my @tkens = split ',', $var;
my @user;
foreach my $tken (@tkens)
{
    push @user, $tken."\@domain.com"; # `.` after `$tken` for concatenation  
}
print join(',', @user), "\n"
```

Output:

```
username1@domain.com,username2@domain.com,username3@domain.com
```